# Select statement in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for an Select statement in Sql Server, I want some thing like this

```
SELECT                 
   st.segment_guid as ST_Segment_Guid,
   ST.ST02 as [Transaction_Set_ControlNumber],      
   N1.N102  AS [Payer_Name],                        
   N1.N104  AS [Payer_Identification_Number],
   N1.N102  AS [Payee_Name],
   N1.N104 END AS [Payee_Identification_Number],

FROM X12_ST ST
   INNER JOIN X12_N1 N1 ON st.segment_guid = n1.parent_segment_guid 
where ST.x12_interchange_guid = '3ff7d629-0036-4deb-bb69-31f8c159f71e'
```

Here if `N1.LoopID` is `'1000A'` then it should select from payer columns. If `N1.LoopID` is  `'1000B'` then it should select from payee columns.

And for ST.x12_interchange_guid = '3ff7d629-0036-4deb-bb69-31f8c159f71e' there should be one payer and one payee, I want bother payer , payee For that ST.x12_interchange_guid in a single line when it is selected.

Comment: Read up on the CASE statement.

Comment: Wow. ANSI X12 EDI via SQL. You're a brave person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get two things on the same line usually implies aggregation (or in some cases a join).  You'll need aggregation along with a case statement:

```
SELECT st.segment_guid as ST_Segment_Guid,
       ST.ST02 as [Transaction_Set_ControlNumber],      
       max(case when N1.LoopID = '1000A' then N1.N102 end) AS [Payer_Name],                        
       max(case when N1.LoopID = '1000A' then N1.N104 end) AS [Payer_Identification_Number],
       max(case when N1.LoopID <> '1000A' then N1.N102 end) AS [Payee_Name],
       max(case when N1.LoopID <> '1000A' then N1.N104 end) AS [Payee_Identification_Number]
FROM X12_ST ST INNER JOIN
     X12_N1 N1
     ON st.segment_guid = n1.parent_segment_guid 
where ST.x12_interchange_guid = '3ff7d629-0036-4deb-bb69-31f8c159f71e'
group by st.segment_guid, ST.ST02;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
  WHEN N1.LoopID = '1000A'
    THEN (Column from Payer Table)
  ELSE SomeOtherColumn
END AS theColumn
```

[Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: You should include explanatory text here, in addition to the external link. Code-only answers, like link-only answers, are discouraged. (You should also show multiple CASE branches, as you've only covered the `LoopID = '1000A'` choice, and not the `'1000B'` (or `'2000A'` or some other value) possibility.)

Comment: @KenWhite My answer provides the OP a sample block and guidance towards figuring out the complete solution on their own.

Comment: The "guidance" works great, until the point it's unavailable for some reason (temporarily off-line, moved, or whatever). Answers here should contain sufficient information to stand on their own, with external links used for *additional information*. You've not provided the *initial information* to which it could be an addition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions...This is the 1st time iam posting question here....Exactly my question is for ST.x12_interchange_guid = '3ff7d629-0036-4deb-bb69-31f8c159f71e' there should be one payer and one payee, I want bother payer , payee For that ST.x12_interchange_guid in a single line when it is selected.